# How to convert SQL Syntax to EF Core

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-core

SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FUND_SOURCE
FROM [dbo].[PROPERTY_TRANSACTION]
WHERE FUND_SOURCE != ''
  AND FUND_SOURCE IS NOT NULL ;
```

I tried this EF Core code:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<PROPERTYTRANSACTION>(true);
    var query = _ctx.PROPERTY_TRANSACTION
                    .Where(fs => !(fs.FUND_SOURCE == null && fs.FUND_SOURCE.Trim() == string.Empty))
                    .Distinct();
return query.Where(predicate);
```

This EF Core code returns all the rows from the database.

Can you please help me how to distinct all the row of the database?

Comment: `FUND_SOURCE != '' AND FUND_SOURCE IS NOT NULL` <> `!(fs.FUND_SOURCE == null && fs.FUND_SOURCE.Trim() == string.Empty)`. Is a column likely to be both `null` _and_ `Empty` for a row?

Comment: Ref: [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `FUND_SOURCE` -

```
var query = _ctx.PROPERTY_TRANSACTION
    .Where(fs => !(fs.FUND_SOURCE == null && fs.FUND_SOURCE.Trim() == string.Empty))
    .Select(fs => fs.FUND_SOURCE).Distinct();
```

Comment: Hi @Felix I updated the code. I tried your code but there's an error saying https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1503?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1503)

Comment: you don't say anything about types or type conversion... How is that error relevant to the code in question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IsNullOrEmpty`

```
var result = _ctx.PROPERTY_TRANSACTION
    .Where(fs => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fs.FUND_SOURCE))
    .Select(fs => fs.FUND_SOURCE)
    .ToList()
    .Distinct();
```